# How to use ArrayList Model Globally in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

Can anyone tell me how to make ArrayList Globally as a model.

Comment: Please try asking the question in a different way.  Do mean you want to make an instance of an ArrayList globally available?   "as a model"?

Comment: I have seen that we can put objects in arrayList. But how to use arraylist with the setter getter In my project & how I can access Objects Values Globally. I am a biginner so I want to right way for handle this in android Project . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can also pass arraylist in Intent

```
Bundle intentbundle = new Bundle();
        intentbundle.putStringArrayList("arrList",arrList);

       intent.putExtras(intentbundle);

       startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But for this it should be parceable or serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
public class YourClass extends Activity {

    private List<Integer> mMyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Or if you like to share it within multiple activities/classes, you can use a singleton:

```
public final class MyClass {
    private static final MyClass instance = new MyClass();

    private List<Integer> mMyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static MyClass getInstance() { 
        return instance;
    }

    private MyClass() {
    }
}
```

And call:

```
MyClass.getInstance().mMyList
```

Comment: Please Tell me about toString() method which is used for return values from arrayList in android ? Thanks

Comment: Be careful with the singleton.  If only MyClass should be able to add/remove values from the ArrayList, return a copy of mMyList and add "add()" and "remove()" methods to the class.

Comment: Sir! I am confusued how to get Values which is in ArrayList Objects.

Comment: What kind of ArrayList do you want? For String, for integer? Which aproarch do you prefer, just the global one? Try this link for more information about arraylist http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html